# Testing my Filter's in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, karma-jasmine

I have a filter, which has a dependency on $translate. The below show is the code of the filter.

```
.filter('displayDate', function($translate) {
    "use strict";
    return function(dateValue) {
        if (!dateValue) return '';
        var dateRewrite = new Date(dateValue);
        var locale = $translate.use();
        return dateRewrite.getDate()+' '+dateRewrite.toLocaleString(locale, { month: "long" })+' '+dateRewrite.getFullYear();
    };
});
```

I am trying to write the test case using Jasmine and PhantomJs as my browser and karma as load runner. Below is the code for test case.

```
describe('Filter', function() {
    "use strict";
    beforeEach(module('UI.Filter'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $translate){

    }));

    describe('Testing Filter', function() {
        it('Check for Date',
        inject(function(displayDateFilter) {
            expect(displayDateFilter('2010-11-18T16:34:41.000Z')).toBe('18 November 2010');
        }));
    });
});
```

I am facing problem in $translate to load as a dependency. How do I test this filter. The error that I get on PhantomJs
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$translateProvider%20%3C-%20$translate%20%3C-%20displayDateFilter

Comment: I'm seeing a few basic problems, including a misspelled parameter ("displayDateFilterm") and the fact that you don't actually do anything in your beforeEach injection. Have you reviewed https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject ?

Comment: Have edited my code, I am not getting a idea to use translate as a dependency.

Comment: I solved the problem, there were some dependency issue on my filter module. Actually, the text at angularjs link explains!!

Comment: Awesome! You should post your solution as an answer here and self-accept it.